# Error while adding engine to cordova (Thym) in eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, cordova, eclipse-plugin, cordova-plugins

When I am trying to add an engine (Android) to Cordova (Thym plugin) in eclipse I get the following error

> Could not retrieve and parse downloadable platform information for
>   (android)

due to which I can't run my application.

Also I would like to mention that I am working behind a proxy which I have already configured within "Network Connections" in eclipse.

Kindly tell me how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Try updating to Neon amd it's newer version of Thym maybe